# I'm getting an "Execution Timed Out" error?

Tags: python, algorithm

I'm trying to improve my algorithm skills. When I run my code, I get an "Execution Timed Out" error.

## Pseudocode

```
[This is writen in pseudocode]
if(number is even) number = number / 2
if(number is odd) number = 3*number + 1
```

## My Code

```
def hotpo(n):
    calculator = 0
    while n >= 1:
        if n % 2 == 0:
            n = n / 2
        else:
            n = 3 * n + 1
        calculator = calculator + 1
    return calculator
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. What did you input to the function? This is an implementation of the Collatz Conjecture, yeah?

Comment: Hello, I found it nice. :) I entered 5 in the function. Yes, Collatz.

Comment: It should be `while n > 1:` ; furthermore, better replace `n = n/2` with `n = n//2`, because n/2 will return a float, and you might get an error later due to the imprecision of float calculus.

Comment: I did not know that. Thank you for teaching me something new. :) @Swifty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are dividing number by 2 if number is even but multiplying it by 3 and adding 1 into it.

so for any number it will keep doing this
2,1,4,2,1,4,2,1,4,2,1,4,2,1,4,.....

you just have to change condition to `n>1` in while loop

because at last 2 will come and it got divided by 2, then n becomes 1 then again it will consider 1 as odd as per your condition then again 1*3+1=4 and again 4/2=2 and so on...

I hope you understood..